# joomla 3, how to get style parameters in module template

Tags: php, templates, joomla

Tell me please how can i get the parameters from templateDetails.xml in module template, for example located here: templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/default.php?

I can get this parameters in the index.php file (templates/beez3/index.php), but i want get it in the templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/default.php.

Maybe I incorrectly formulated question. I need to get the style settings of the template which set in the admin panel. How can I get them?

Comment: I think when you say "module template" you don't mean a Joomla module, you mean a component. Is that right?

Comment: yes! but it doesn't matter, because i want to get the parameters in any module template or component template in templates/beez3/html/

Comment: Maybe I incorrectly formulated question. I need to get the style settings of the template which set in the admin panel. How can I get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
$template = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true);
```

will give you the object with the current template parameters.

Comment: I encountered a problem with Joomla 3 when using this line in a module template because `$template` is a global variable. The solution is to use another variable name instead of `$template`. For example `$myTemplate`.

Comment: $template is not a global variable but it is possible it is defined somewhere else in your code.